# How can I link CSS parameters to a javascript img?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added an image with Javascript to a webpage, but I don't know how to modify it or place it. How can I link CSS to the image, or can I modifiy it without CSS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PingPongKép</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>



 <script>

    function ilonaKep() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'img/ilona.jpg';
  document.body.appendChild(img);


}


    </script>

<p>Let's See the image

   <script>
    ilonaKep();
    </script>

   </p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: give it a class,id then add css to id,class

Comment: You can apply CSS by using element ID,Class,Tagname and apply style like this.
**document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.width = "200px";**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery makes this quite easy. Apply any styling you want on the image in the `style` quotes of the image

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p> Lets see the image: </p>

        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                addImage();

                function addImage() {
                    $('body').append('<img style="any css styling in here" src="img/ilona.jpg">');
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have just started to learn Javascript, should I learn jquery paralell or just after javascript?

Comment: Hi Ivan :) If my answer fixed your problem kindly mark it as answered :) I would recommened JQuery. Its not much different to base javascript but it will make your life a ton easier. In my opinion JQuery does everything javascript can do in less code :)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has the ability to set an element's attribute,

```
img.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Alternatively if you don't want inline CSS, you could add the CSS to your CSS file and give the image a class using jquery

```
$("img").addClass("myImage");
```

Comment: <script>
    
    function ilonaKep() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'img/ilona.jpg';
  document.body.appendChild(img);
        

}
     
     
    </script>
    
<p>Let's See the image
   
   <script>
    ilonaKep.setAttribute("style", "width: 100px");
    </script>

You mean like this? This doesn't work.